# Changing the display name of a variable in the VS Locals Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

We have a custom scripting language that generates chunks of C++. The way it has been designed, it generates "thisPtr" as the "this" object for each class type in the C++ side.

I was wondering if there is a way to extend the locals/watch window so it displays "thisPtr" as "this", so that it would be simpler for users to type look-ups into the watch window.

Comment: I'm going to go with both of "no" and "please god no"

Comment: I agree. I just needed someone else to say this to give me backup that it's a bad idea.

Comment: They still want it though, so if anyone has any ideas...?